# Multi-value custom fields for events

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, multi-record

I have events that often include downloadable materials. Whether or not there are downloads, what exactly they are, and the number of downloads related to a particular event is variable and unique to each event. Right now I have to add download links to the body of the event description.

This is a situation that would be perfectly handled by a multi-value custom dataset attached to the event, but alas, as far as I can tell you can't yet add multi-value datasets to events. Anyone know of a plugin, work-around, patch, or even a plan to change the functionality in the near future?

Answer (score 2):

Multi-Value custom dataset is only available for Contacts and Contact Type custom fields. But i believe it is possible to make it available for Events by creating an extension and adding code using hooks to hack the current behaviour in CiviCRM. I am not sure if anyone has a plan or willing to add this functionality in future version of CiviCRM.